# Using the Yeo Johnson transformation in the car package

Tags: r, function, transformation

I think I must be doing something incorrectly with the Yeo-Johnson transformation, as other R users seem to be able to get it to work. Every time I execute the function, I get an error.

```
library(car)
mydata <- read.csv("R_import.csv", header=TRUE)
test <- yjPower(mydata,0.5,jacobian.adjusted=FALSE)
```

After I run this, I receive:

> Error in if (abs(lambda) <= 1e-06) log(U) else ((U^lambda) - 1)/lambda : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I've tried different datasets and different starting lambda and nothing seems to change. Does anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: We need a (minimal) reproducible example please; I can't reproduce this.  Results of `sessionInfo()` would be useful too.

Comment: I *can* get this error message if I use a data frame that contains factors (but I get meaningful warnings about factors in addition to the error message ...)

Comment: Doesn't happen to me with those parameters and the sample dataset used in `?yjPower` that does have an NA as its first value. Perhaps your installation of `car` is broken and you need to reinstall.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's literally all that I've run. The data in the csv is just a set of four numeric variables, all weakly positive. One of them is a dummy variable, which was my first guess as to where the problem was, but removing it didn't change anything. I'll try the sample dataset and reinstall, hopefully that's all it is.

Comment: Update - I found my error, and it was quite silly. There needs to be a starting lambda specified for each variable to be transformed.

i.e., lambda=c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)

Hope this helps someone with a similar oversight.